# Why generation of uuid4 is faster than uuid1?

Tags: python, uuid

This is the code I am using,

```
from uuid import uuid1, uuid4

def test1(n): 
    for _ in range(0,n): 
         uuid1() 
                                                   

def test4(n): 
    for _ in range(0,n): 
         uuid4()
```

The results of the run

```
In [65]: %timeit test1(1000000)                           
22.1 s ± 1.01 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [66]: %timeit test4(1000000)                           
5.55 s ± 600 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As you can see uuid4 generation seems to 5 times faster than uuid1. I know understand uuid scheme https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Where does uuid1 spends it time ?

Comment: This is a question you could answer yourself with use of a sampling profiler.

Comment: My guess is the host lookup is the part that takes time. You can try to verify this yourself, by passing in a fixed host as the node argument to `uuid1` and see if it is faster.